# Responsive HTML site produces 'black' background for header on smaller devices or screens

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm working on the following site: http://flask-priceline.f8n9uir55a.ap-southeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

It's just a development sandbox at the moment. On a full screen (desktop) it looks great, but when you make the browser narrow or view on mobile, the white header/navbar at the top goes black for some reason and I can't figure out why? I'm no HTML/CSS guru, so am a bit stumped... Pic below:

All good:
[image]
Not so good (when smaller):
[image]

Comment: now u want to remove that black color? 'm right ?

Comment: On your style.css file on line 3146, changed the background color to this:

`background: transparent;`

because the `.header_area .navbar` its background color was set to #000 which is black. Also it is under **@media with max-width of 991px** it means, with in that range of device includes mobile, the background will change to black instead of white.

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked.. well it worked for the background, but now the hamburger menu is invisible or missing? (See second image in original post) Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, duh me, it's white lol.. of course it's there just invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your style.css file on line 3146 and look that

```
.header_area .navbar {
    background: #0b0707; }
```

and change it to the `background: transparent;`

```
.header_area .navbar {
        background: transparent; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked.. well it worked for the background, but now the hamburger menu is invisible or missing? (See second image in original post) Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, duh me, it's white lol.. of course it's there just invisible.